# Reading delimited data from text file into different RDDs

Tags: java, apache-spark

Am new to Apache Spark java
I have a text file delimited by space as below

```
3,45.25,23.45
5,22.15,19.35
4,33.24,12.45
2,15.67,21.22
```

Here the columns mean:

- 1st column: index value
- 2nd column: latitude values
- 3rd column: longitude values

Am trying to parse this data into 2 or 3 RDDs (or pair RDDs). This is my code so far:

```
JavaRDD<String> data = sc.textFile("hdfs://data.txt");

JavaRDD<Double> data1 = data.flatMap(
  new FlatMapFunction<String, Double>() {
    public Iterable<Double> call(Double data) {
      return Arrays.asList(data.split(","));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (use Java 8 for better readability)?

```
JavaRDD<String> data = sc.textFile("hdfs://data.txt");
JavaRDD<Tuple3<Integer, Float, Float>> parsedData = data.map((line) -> line.split(","))
        .map((line) -> new Tuple3<>(parseInt(line[0]), parseFloat(line[1]), parseFloat(line[2])))
        .cache(); // Cache parsed to avoid recomputation in subsequent .mapToPair calls

JavaPairRDD<Integer, Float> latitudeByIndex = parsedData.mapToPair((line) -> new Tuple2<>(line._1(), line._2()));
JavaPairRDD<Integer, Float> longitudeByIndex = parsedData.mapToPair((line) -> new Tuple2<>(line._1(), line._3()));
JavaPairRDD<Integer, Tuple2<Float, Float>> pointByIndex = parsedData.mapToPair((line) -> new Tuple2<>(line._1(), new Tuple2<>(line._2(), line._3())));
```