# read specific columns from a csv file in Spark using Java

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a `csv` file and I want to read specific columns from this `csv` file using `Java` in `Spark` and form an `RDD` of it. The code that I have written so far reads every column and forms the `RDD`:

```
JavaRDD<String> data = sc.textFile("hdfs://file1.csv");
```

I have a variable `ArrayList<String> arr= new ArrayList<String>();` which has indexes of columns I want to read from the `csv` file. How do modify my code to read specific columns from the `csv` file?

A sample data is as follows:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6
12,32.4,2,emp1,11,21
17,33.6,2,emp1,11,41
21,32.1,2,emp2,11,60
42,30.4,2,emp3,11,57
37,37.5,2,emp2,11,43
```

Comment: You have to read the whole file. You later can `map` over the lines, and split the sting or load into a dataframe.

Comment: @cricket_007 How can I map over the lines and load the specific columns into dataframe?

Comment: `data.map(line -> { // do stuff } )`... There's plenty of examples of that in the Spark documentation

Comment: @cricket_007 I am new to this so I am having a bit difficulty in getting the way to do it. I went through some samples(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29442211/reading-delimited-data-from-text-file-into-different-rdds) but couldn't figure out a way to do it. Is it possible if you could provide a way to do this?

Comment: That question seems to be exactly what you want, no? `line[x]` gives you a *specific* column `x` of the `line` that was `split(",")` from the file when you `map` a function across it...

Comment: @cricket_007 the problem I am having in understanding is that in that example the columns are static(`int`,`float`,`float`) but in my case the columns are no static(there index is stored in a arraylist). So I am unable to get how `JavaRDD<Tuple3<Integer, Float, Float>> parsedData = data.map((line) -> line.split(","))
        .map((line) -> new Tuple3<>(parseInt(line[0]), parseFloat(line[1]), parseFloat(line[2])))
        .cache();` in the example should be turned for my case?

Comment: You haven't shown your data, so how are we supposed to know that? If your columns aren't static, then I don't think you can reliably use Spark the way that you have done

Comment: @cricket_007 by static I meant that the indexes of the columns that I want to select are stored in a `Arraylist` named `arr`. So if `arr` has 3 indexes then I want to select those 3 columns from the csv file.And all the data are in String format (for simplicity).

Comment: Then you might be better off with a dataframe so you can access columns by name rather than index. Still not sure what your data looks like. Can you please [edit] to show a few rows?

Comment: @cricket_007 I have edited my question to show a sample output

Comment: Thanks. Are you required to use Java?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes using Java is a requirement.

Comment: Alright, just to let you know, though, PySpark has a direct way to get your CSV into a DataFrame with `sparkContext.read.csv('input.csv', header=True)`... I'll try to find the equivalent in Java

Comment: Seems to be what you are looking for (make sure to read the full README installation steps first). https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv#java-api

Comment: @cricket_007 the example you mentioned would require me to install databricks api right? I have to use just the normal spark without any other api

Comment: Such a strange requirement... Well, then you are stuck with `line[columnHeaders.indexOf("col1")]` to get the first column from an arraylist of `columnHeaders`